# How to get if image is touched and not the transparent background? LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, 2d-games

i have a picture of a head and its on a transparent background and i want to get if the head is clicked not the area behind his head.  this is what i had for the entire image not the image withing the box. pretend the grey part is the transparent part. i want nothing to happen when that area is clicked. only his body.
link to picture->[link to picture](http://edge-img.datpiff.com/m199acf7/Kanye_West_The_Yeezy_Effect-front-large.jpg)

```
  stage.addListener(new ClickListener()
   {
       @Override
       public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int a , int b)
       {   
          if(box.equals(stage.hit(x,y,false)))
           {
             box.setPosition(100, 100);
              point.play();
              score++;   
            }       
          return true;
      } 
     });
```

Comment: Is the image an actor in the stage? because then you would put the listener on the box not on the stage.

Comment: yes i tried that but itt still goes off if i click in the transparent background and not the head. added link to a picture^

Comment: its because the picture is technically taking up the same width and height of the background. Instead you will need to inside of the touch down check to see if the clicks x and y were in the area of the picture that you want to have the click work. Also if it is a click remember there is a clicked method instead of the touchdown method if your looking for that.

Comment: but how.. i know that

Comment: The method gives you x and y of the touch use that in an if statement to compare it with where you want a touch to be allowed. Maybe break it up into 2 rectangles of where touches should be allowed